# Should the (sde) tag be found through typing "differential"?

Tags: feature-request, tagging, tag-management

Should the [sde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sde) tag be found through typing "differential"? The [pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pde) tag can be found that way. The [differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-equations) tag can be found through [ode](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ode).

Comment: We could create a tag [tag:stochastic-differential-equations] and make [tag:sde] a [synonym](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) of that.

Comment: That's too many characters (33). Even [tag:stochastic-differential-eqns] has 28.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Brilliant.

Comment: Maybe [tag:stochas-differential-eqns]? (If the goal is to have differential in the name) But it's starting to not really look good.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Never mind. Let us use your idea.

Comment: It's not possible, @Jack, there is a 25-character limit on tag names.

Comment: IMO stochastic is rather more relevant than differential. One could go for stochastic-differential or stochastic-differential-e

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oh, barto was replying to you. Okay never mind then. Thanks.

Comment: I'd go for the most informative, which would be [tag:stochastic-differention-e]. The full name can always be mentioned in the tag excerpt so I don't think it's necessary to have "equations" or "eqns" in the name. Writing "differential-e" in the tag box gives 3 hits now while "differential" gives 10, so adding the "e" seems useful.

Comment: *differential, not differention

Comment: We should also adapt the tag wiki and excerpt for [tag:differential-equations] to mention [tag:sde] (currently it only mentions [tag:pde]).